# React app backend firestore useEffect not working correctly

Tags: reactjs, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to keep track of the number of visitors my website gets using firestore as a backend.

I have two functions in my useEffect hook getVistorCount, and updateVistorCount. getVistorCount gets the doc containing the vistor_count variable from firestore and saves that array of data to state.

My updateVistorCount function gets the id and data of the document I am trying to update from state. The problem is that my state is initialized to an empty array so when I try to get the id and vistor_count from state I get the error "Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'id')" because the array from state is empty.

I am also getting the following warning in VSCode: "React Hook useEffect has missing dependencies: 'numberOfVistors' and 'portfolioStatesRef'. Either include them or remove the dependency array"

Here is the current code:

```
const portfolioStatesRef = collection(db, "portfolio-stats")
  
  useEffect (() => {

    let sessionKey = sessionStorage.getItem("sessionKey")
    
    const getVistorCount = async () => {
      const dataFromPortfolioStatsCollection = await getDocs(portfolioStatesRef)

      setnumberOfVistors(dataFromPortfolioStatsCollection.docs.map((doc) => {
         return  ({ ...doc.data(), id: doc.id })
      }))
    }

    const updateVistorCount = async () => {

      const portfolioStatsDoc = doc(db, "portfolio-stats", numberOfVistors[0].id)
      const updatedFields = {vistor_count: numberOfVistors[0].vistor_count + 1}
      await updateDoc(portfolioStatsDoc, updatedFields)
    }

    getVistorCount()
    
    if (sessionKey === null)
    {
      sessionStorage.setItem("sessionKey", "randomString")  
      updateVistorCount()
    }
    
    }, [])
```

Comment: How often do you want to run the code in the useEffect ? Do you want to run it only once when the component renders, or do you want to run it every time that something changes ?

Comment: Yes only once when the component

Comment: If your state is initialized as an empty array , when does it get assigned a new value ?
You might want to do the updateVistorCount in an other useffect when the value of your state changes with the state value as dependency.

Comment: It get changed getvistorcount function

Comment: Yes. Use 2 useEffect. One for updateVistorCount one for updateVistorCount

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe using two effects can achieve what you want. First to get visitors:

```js
useEffect (() => {

    let sessionKey = sessionStorage.getItem("sessionKey")
    
    const getVistorCount = async () => {
      const dataFromPortfolioStatsCollection = await getDocs(portfolioStatesRef)

      setnumberOfVistors(dataFromPortfolioStatsCollection.docs.map((doc) => {
         return  ({ ...doc.data(), id: doc.id })
      }))
    }

    getVistorCount()
    
 }, [])
```

Second to update count

```js
useEffect (() => {
    if(!numberOfVistors.length) return;

    const updateVistorCount = async () => {
      const portfolioStatsDoc = doc(db, "portfolio-stats", numberOfVistors[0].id)
      const updatedFields = {vistor_count: numberOfVistors[0].vistor_count + 1}
      await updateDoc(portfolioStatsDoc, updatedFields)
   }

   updateVistorCount()
    
 }, [numberOfVistors])
```

Comment: this line: if(!numberOfVistors.length) return; solved the problem as well as your suggestion to use two separate useEffects. If I understand it correctly we needed that first if statement to check and see if our numberOfVistors state got the data from firebase before we try to update the count. I also added numberOfVistors to the getCount useEffect because I wanted to get the updated count of visitors whenever it was changed. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Yes, if the state is initialized as empty you needed to check before. And if you need to run the effect after a state change, you need add the state as dependency.